# JavaScript - stop timer on focus event

Tags: javascript

I have a script that changes the text in a textbox every 2 seconds. I want to make it stop (the timer) and clear the textbox when the user clicks and focuses on the textbox.

```
var text = ["1", " 2", "3"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("txt1");

setInterval(change, 2000);

function change() {
document.getElementById("txt1").value = text[counter]; //data is the element
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { 
        counter = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp example no. 2

Answer (score 2):

Update your input type like

```
 <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

Also update

```
setInterval(change, 2000);
```

to

```
var tt=setInterval(change, 2000);
```

Add myFunction in your script

```
function myFunction(){
   clearInterval(tt);
   document.getElementById("txt1").value = "";
}
```

Comment: And after calling `clearInterval(tt)`, call `document.getElementById("txt1").value = "";`

Answer (score 1):

Store the interval id when you call `setInterval()`:

```
var interval = setInterval(change, 2000);
```

and cancel it, later, in a `focus()` handler:

```
function stopit()
{
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = false;
    elem.value = "";
  }
}

if (elem.addEventListener) {
  elem.addEventListener('focus', stopit, false); 
} else if (elem.attachEvent)  {
  elem.attachEvent('onfocus', stopit);
}
```

Note that `stopit()` only clears the interval (and the text) once -- this way, if the user types something, focuses elsewhere, then re-focuses, we don't discard their input.

example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/AtxEr

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

// When you set the interval

interval_variable = setInterval(change, 2000);

// When you want to stop the execution of "change"

clearInterval(interval_variable);

Answer (score 0):

The really simple solution would be to just check if the input has focus inside the function, and `document.activeElement` holds the focused element so just comparing that to `elem` and returning if they are the same would do it

```
var text    = ["I want a smartphone with a big screen", "I don't want a smartphone made by a korean company", "I want a LED TV with high refresh rate"];
var counter = 0;
var elem    = document.getElementById("txt1");

elem.addEventListener('focus', function() {this.value=''}, false);

setInterval(change, 2000);

function change() {
    if (document.activeElement == elem) return;

    elem.value = text[counter];
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pLC6A/3/)